# is it possible to map numpad differently?

Tags: key-bindings, macos, keyboard-layout

Currently, the numpad does the usual things(input numbers and so on). numlock does nothing.

I wonder if you can differentiate numbers/char entered on the numpad from those typed on the main section of the keyboard.

I am on MacOS if relevant(VimR).

Comment: See `:h terminal-key-codes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are special keys `<k0>` to `<k9>` and `<kPlus>`, `<kMinus>`, `<kDivide>`, `<kMultiply>`, `<kEnter>`, and `<kPoint>`, which can be mapped separately, e.g.,

```
inoremap <k0> Zero
inoremap <k1> One
...
```

I checked this with GVim running on Windows 7; the behavior on macOS might be different.

Comment: Didn't work for me neither in Vimr nor in neovim on terminal(iTerm).

Comment: @eyalkarni Can you check if in insert mode `<ctrl-k>` followed by one of the keypad numbers shows you a special key notation? If yes, you can use this notation on the left side of your mapping. Strangely, on my computer this didn't work (only a normal digit with SpecialKey-highlighting was temporarily shown), but with the `'showcmd'` option set `^k5` (for example) was shown in the last line of the screen. This means the key is recognized as a special key, but I don't know how to determine the notation for the left side of the mapping from this information.

Comment: I don't get any modifier in <c-k>. Supposedly, because my keyboard isn't really supported in macos.